# Converting a .exe c++ file (that creates a window) into a .dll c++ file and use that .dll file in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a .exe program in C++ that only shows a window. How can I convert that .exe program into a .dll file and then how can I access that .dll file with C# so I can show that window. Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <windows.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: If you find something converts .exe to .dll or to the original code, let me know, we are going to be rich. In other words edit your title.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to create the window in C#?

Comment: I am writing a Direct3D application in C++ and I want to use it for my C# program.

Comment: Would you consider creating this as an ActiveX control, you can host that in your C# application. You could also return your created window handle from a function exported from your DLL - you'll need a WinForms app for that: HWND MakeMySpecialWindow();

Comment: Thanks Peter R, I will give it a try. But wich hInstance must I use for my window?

Comment: Your C++ program does nothing. There's nothing at all to port.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1. If you have a c++ program you can build it as a `dll` by following this
   [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx), assuming you use visual studio.
2. In order to use a `c++` `dll` within a `c#` program you need to read:

   - [using C++ DLL in C# windows application:Getting error "Entry point not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508310/using-c-dll-in-c-sharp-windows-applicationgetting-error-entry-point-not-foun)
   - [Creating C++ .dll for use by Excel & C# (32/64bit Window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309846/creating-c-dll-for-use-by-excel-c-sharp-32-64bit-window)
   - [Using C++ Class DLL in C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569603/using-c-class-dll-in-c-sharp-application)
   - [Using C++ DLL in C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995513/using-c-dll-in-c-sharp-project)

Comment: But what to do with the hInstance variable? I need that for initializing my window.

Comment: read this as well http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/066a1a5d-b463-4988-9997-ce5e519bf16d/