# Converting .out file into .dll in cygwin command line

Tags: c, dll, cygwin, executable

We have built our project into a .out file using cygwin. We have to call functions from that project using python script. For that we need .dll file.

Is there any way or command to convert a .out file into a .dll using cygwin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the format of the `.out` file?  A `.dll` is usually created from a language like C, C++, or C#, not Python.  (`out` is a C# keyword)

Comment: our .out is created form C language

Comment: we want to call functions of C from python by loading .dll of C file into python like: lib=ctypes.CDLL("file.dll").We have only .out file of that C file.So kindly suggest how to convert that .out into .dll in cygwin

Comment: Aha!  I see now, a.out is the default executable name from gcc.  How was it compiled, and does it have a `main()` function?  If it does, then it can't be a DLL.  Does the C code use the Python API?  If not, then you will need to use the `ctypes` standard library.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have an executable compiled with default arguments (often named things like `a.out`). I'm not sure that you can convert this to a .dll without some difficulty.

Do you have access to the source code? In which case, you can follow [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx), as given in [0x90's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121835/converting-a-exe-c-file-that-creates-a-window-into-a-dll-c-file-and-use).

Comment: In that case, you need to build it into a .dll, as described in the linked example or, if you want to do it just with cygwin (without Visual Studio), then try [this](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html).